# What's the difference if this limit is approached from the left/right/neither?

Tags: calculus

Evaluate

$$\lim_{x \to -2^{-}} \frac{x^2-3x-18}{x^2-4}$$

The solution doesn't exist in this situation. Though if the limit approached from the right side $(x \to -2^{+})$ or neither side $(x \to -2)$ would that change the solution?

Comment: There are mistakes in your question. 2 or -2? And omitting the sign means BOTH sides.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisGagnon Asking what the solution would be for when x->-2+, and the solution for x->2

Comment: What do you mean by "solution does not exist"? The limit when $x\to 2^-$ is $\frac{\text{negative}}{0^-}=+\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will. The numerator in that expression is always negative when you're close to -2, but the sign of the denominator depends on which side you approach $-2$.

So, if you approach it from one side the limit will be $-\infty$ and if you approach it from the other side it will be $\infty$